# Problems getting attachment of invoice in exact online

Tags: php, exact-online, picqer-exact-php-client

I'm using the library picqer/exact-online and I was getting attachments of an invoice I just created like this:
However this suddenly stopped working a few days ago, can anybody help here?

Following error occurs:

> Picqer\Financials\Exact\ApiException: Error 400: Unrecognized 'Edm.Guid' literal 'guid''' in '12'. (uncaught exception) at /var/web/partners/vendor/picqer/exact-php-client/src/Picqer/Financials/Exact/Connection.php line 560 while creating an invoice.

```
$printedInvoice = new PrintedSalesInvoice($this->exact);
$printedInvoice->InvoiceID = $invoice->InvoiceID;
$documentData = $printedInvoice->save();

$attachment   = new DocumentAttachment($this->exact);
$attachments  = $attachment->filter(sprintf(
    "Document eq guid'%s'", 
    $documentData['Document']
));
```

Comment: create space between guid'%s' and check

Comment: What is the actual URL sent? What is in `$documentData['Document']`?

Comment: Problem was discovered and there was a hidden error creating the PrintedSalesInvoice because my invoice had an end date set to a non-existing financial year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was discovered and there was a hidden error creating the PrintedSalesInvoice because my invoice had an end date set to a non-existing financial year.

Comment: If it worked for you, can you please share your code with us?
Actually I want order & invoice data, but not able to get it
Can you please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66475102/how-to-get-fetch-orders-their-invoice-pdfdownloadable-to-magento-2-from-exac